# Xamarin forms community tabview easing when swiping

Tags: xamarin, tabview, xamarin-community-toolkit

I'm using the TabView from Community Toolkit of Xamarin Forms:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/tabview

Works just fine, but i'm not too fond of the transition when swiping.
Is there anyway to change the transition from the current easing to another linear easing? Or preferable the same smooth linear transition it uses when tabbing the tabs?

Answer (score 0):

According to Xamarin.CommunityToolkit API, we can't set the way of swiping. Although, you can try TabbedPage instead. For more information, you can refer to
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page